# generate a list of hashes from a list for every entry of a hash in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following two variables:

```yaml
target_groups:
  - name: http
    port: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
targets:
  - 1.2.3.4
  - 2.3.4.5
```

For an `elb_target_group` task I need a list of hashes as `targets` parameter. So what I'd like to have is a structure like the following:

```yaml
target_groups:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targets:
      - Id: 1.2.3.4
        Port: 80
      - Id: 2.3.4.5
        Port: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targets:
      - Id: 1.2.3.4
        Port: 443
      - Id: 2.3.4.5
        Port: 443
```

So the `targets` entry of each `target_groups` element must be composed of the port of the element and all IPs of the targets list.

I have twisted my head around all map, combine... whatever filter I could find but couldn't come up with a solution.

Actually I don't even need that `targets` element in the list, as long as I can generate a suitable list of hashes on the fly, I'd be happy to do that. My task would look like that:

```yaml
- name: update target groups
  elb_target_group:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    protocol: tcp
    port: "{{ item.port }}"
    state: present
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
    targets: <<NEEDHELPHERE>>
  with_items:
    - { name: http, port: 80 }
    - { name: https, port: 443 }
```

Is this even possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more options.

- Iterate the list and combine the dictionaries. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        tg2: "{{ tg2|d([]) + [item|combine({'targets':_targets})] }}"
      loop: "{{ target_groups }}"
      vars:
        _targets: "{{ dict(targets|product([item.port]))|
                      dict2items(key_name='Id', value_name='Port') }}"
```

gives the updated list of dictionaries

```yaml
  tg2:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targets:
    - Id: 1.2.3.4
      Port: 80
    - Id: 2.3.4.5
      Port: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targets:
    - Id: 1.2.3.4
      Port: 443
    - Id: 2.3.4.5
      Port: 443
```

---

- The next option is putting the code into the vars. For example, the expression below gives the same result

```yaml
    tg2: "{{ target_groups|
             json_query('[].[port]')|
             map('product', targets)|
             map('map', 'zip', ['Port', 'Id'])|
             map('map', 'map', 'reverse')|
             map('map', 'community.general.dict')|
             map('community.general.dict_kv', 'targets')|
             zip(target_groups)|
             map('combine')|
             list }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    target_groups:
      - name: http
        port: 80
      - name: https
        port: 443
    targets:
      - 1.2.3.4
      - 2.3.4.5

    tg2: "{{ target_groups|
             json_query('[].[port]')|
             map('product', targets)|
             map('map', 'zip', ['Port', 'Id'])|
             map('map', 'map', 'reverse')|
             map('map', 'community.general.dict')|
             map('community.general.dict_kv', 'targets')|
             zip(target_groups)|
             map('combine')|
             list }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: tg2
```

---

- Create the structure in Jinja if you want to. For example, the expressions below give the same result too

```yaml
    _tg2: |-
      {% for i in target_groups %}
      -
      {% for k, v in i.items() %}
        {{ k }}: {{ v }}
      {% endfor %}
        targets:
      {% for ip in targets %}
        - Id: {{ ip }}
          Port: {{ i.port }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    tg2: "{{ _tg2|from_yaml }}"
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. As always, if you know how to do it, a lot of things are possible with Ansible.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. This doesn't improve my love for Ansible, however.

Comment: You're welcome. Optionally, put the code into the [vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Answer (score 0):

Still rather ugly, but a slightly more readable solution is to build YAML and use the `to_yaml` filter. I've not found a way to avoid doing this in two steps so far, but this is an example of what I mean:

```
--- # test.yml
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
#  user: root

  vars:
    bar:
      - apple
      - banana
      - carrot
    foo: |-
      {% for x in bar %}
      - greet: "hello {{ x }}"
        farewell: "hello {{ x }}"
      {% endfor %}
  tasks:
    - name: test
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ foo | from_yaml }}"
```

Running:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [test] ******************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test] ******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'greet': 'hello apple', 'farewell': 'hello apple'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "farewell": "hello apple",
        "greet": "hello apple"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'greet': 'hello banana', 'farewell': 'hello banana'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "farewell": "hello banana",
        "greet": "hello banana"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'greet': 'hello carrot', 'farewell': 'hello carrot'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "farewell": "hello carrot",
        "greet": "hello carrot"
    }
}
```